# Is it necessary to repeat the subject after "or" within compound sentences? "He obviously doesn't have a plan, or (he) would have said something."

Tags: conjunctions, subjects

I am confused with the usage of "or". Here is two sentences that confused me:

1. He obviously doesn't have a plan, or he would have said something.
2. He obviously doesn't have a plan, or would have said something.

I have taught that the second sentence is more advisable than the first sentence, yet grammar book which I studying from doesn't say so. Isn't the second "he" unnecessary? I don't know whether in English there is a  incoherency due to using objects which are unnecessary.

Comment: *Or* is a poor choice here. The idea is one of logical deduction and exclusion. In casual usage, you might hear *or, or else, because, for, since*,  or *otherwise*. The latter four require *he*.

Answer (score 0):

"Or" in these examples is not a logical connective: it is more than that. It has the meaning "Or else", and introduces a deduction. The meaning is something like "I know that, because otherwise ... "

If you did not repeat the subject, it would read like a (rather odd) logical connection.